# Unable to use EfficientNet with transfer learning

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, efficientnet

I want to use EfficientNet with transfer learning in the [Eurosat-rgb](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/eurosat) dataset. The problem I have is that it doesn't seem to learn.

First, I start with the following model using transfer learning with MobileNet and it works fine [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5Ggi.jpg)

```
model_base = tf.keras.applications.MobileNet(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=input_shape=(224,224,3))
model_base.trainable=False
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  model_base,
  tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(name="avg_pool"),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax", name="predictions")
])
```

Then, I change from MobileNet to EfficientNetB1, and suddenly it doesn't learn anything [(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5Ggi.jpg).
And then, if I try with model_base.trainable=True, training accuracy improves but not validation accuracy [(3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5Ggi.jpg).

What am I doing wrong?

If I use EfficientNet without tranfer learning I get good results too [(4)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5Ggi.jpg), but it takes a lot of time obviusly.
I've also tried by changing the optimizer from sgd to adam, but it doesn't work neither.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what is happening is that for Mobilenet the preprocessing functtion scales the images between -1 to +1. However for   EfficientNetB1, the the documentation located [here](https://keras.io/api/applications/efficientnet/) states

```
Note: each Keras Application expects a specific kind of input preprocessing.
For EfficientNet, input preprocessing is included as part of the model 
(as a Rescaling layer), and thus tf.keras.applications.efficientnet.preprocess_input
is actually a pass-through function.
EfficientNet models expect their inputs to be float tensors of pixels with values
in the [0-255] range.
```

So when you change from Mobilenet to Efficientnet be sure to remove any rescaling of the pixel values